# Double Linked Queue with specific template

Tags: c++, templates, nodes, deque

I have the intention to do a program based on a Double Linked Deque where nodes have double links and what i want to do is that each node is a "Document with name and priority" (priority = 1 insert from head, prio. = 2 insert from rear). 
Actually my code is like this, but i don't get everything to work with my templates as i don't know how to declare it correctly in the Node.h .

Document.h

```
template<class T>
class Document
{
 private:
  T name;
  T pri;

 public:
  Document(T name, T pri);
};

 template <class T> 
 Document<T>::Document(T name, T pri){
   this->name = name;
   this->pri = pri;      
}
```

Node.h

```
#include "Document.h"
template <class T> class Node{
 public:
  Node();
  Node(const T& item);
  (...other functions...)

private:
 Document<T> document;  //WHERE MY PROBLEM IS!
 Node<T>* next;
 Node<T>* previous;    
};

template <class T> 
Node<T>::Node(const T& item) {
    this->document= new Document<T>(item); //Problem with the declaration
    this->next = nullptr;
    this->previous = nullptr;
}
```

LinkedDeque.h

```
#include "Node.h"
#include "Document.h"
template <class T> class LinkedDeque {
 public:
  LinkedDeque();
  void insertFront(const T& element);
  void insertRear(const T& element);
  (... other functions ...)

private:
  Node<T>* front; //Front de la cua
  Node<T>* rear; //rear de la cua
  int num_elements;
};

template <class T>
void LinkedDeque<T>::insertFront(const T& element){

    Node<T>* aux = new Node<T>(element);

    (...rest of the function...)
}
```

Main.cpp

```
LinkedDeque<Document<string>> deque;

cin >> name >> pri;
Document<string> document(name,pri);
if (pri == "1") {
  deque.insertFront(document);
}else {
  deque.insertRear(document);
}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Are the name and the priority really supposed to be the same type? That doesn't sound right...

Comment: The question is how i can solve it and make it functional

Comment: Please read [ask] and read how to provide a [mcve]. "My code does not work" is not a sufficient description of your problem.

Comment: One obvious problem why `Document<T>(item)` does not work, is because you only declared a constructor which expects two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is that you declared your constructor as

```
     Document(T name, T pri)
```

but you are trying to create a document object by just using just an item like

```
    this->document= new Document<T>(item)
```

so I suggest passing a name and priority to your constructor, that would work.